# Testing a DLL with Boost::Test from command line

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, boost-test

I am developing a DLL in C++ and want to perform unit testing of that DLL using the [Boost Test Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927855/13441) that `test_runner.exe` can be used.

How to obtain `test_runner.exe`?
Are there any ways or locations which does not require to build `boost`?

I installed boost 1.47 from [BoostPro download page](http://www.boostpro.com/download/), but there is no test_runner.exe there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build one yourself from sources. It has no extra dependencies, only Boost.Test itself.

1. You can bootstrap boost installation
   Download source of boost, unzip and run `bootstrap.bat`.
2. Then build `bjam` and run build command under `libs/test/tools/test_runner`.
   `bjam.exe` should exist in unpacked distribution.
   Switch current folder to `libs/test/tools/test_runner` and run `bjam.exe` from it with required parameters (platform, configuration, etc...).
   Output `console_test_runner.exe` will be available in `bin.v2\libs\test\tools\console_test_runner`

Comment: Gennadiy, I finally resolved my initial issue – when console_test_runner.exe catches exception and output error message, it is trimmed to 512 chars – this is limited by constant REPORT_ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE in file boost\test\impl\execution_monitor.ipp . Can you increase it, say to something like 16384? 
512 is absolutely not enough, especially with template types and using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION to have detailed error message.
I checked in boost 1.52 – it is still 512 bytes.
(I am not sure if it is good idea to write this suggestion here, but I am not familiar how to make suggestions to boost)